# What is the negative impact of assigning a consistent GA clientId across devices/browsers

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-optimize

**Context**

I am implementing Google Optimize and want to insure users are assigned the same variant across all of their devices/browsers. Google Optimize initially utilises the Google Analytics clientId to decide what variant should be applied (from then on a cookie is used).

To achieve this outcome I am assigning my websites user UUID as the clientId as follows:

`ga('create', ..., 'clientId': 'MY_USER_ID')`

This has the desired outcome, and does not appear to cause any negative side effects in my GA data.

**Question**

Are there any negative side effects to my GA data as a result of overriding the default clientId, and is this considered acceptable practice?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to track cross browser device activity is to use `User ID` and not `Client ID`.

The `userId` field, should be kept stable, non-personally identifiable ID to represent a unique user across devices/browsers. And can be tracked in your Google Analytics account in a separate view.

While `clientId` is used for tracking unique users and is stored in a cookie, if cookies are removed, GA will assign them a new `clientId`. Another drawback is cookie definitions might change in future.

As Optimize uses clientId to render the variants, your workaround is working but not the recommended way to go. Let Google Optimize do it's job :)

You can read more about [User ID implementation in the official guide here](https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/6009743?hl=en&ref_topic=1007027)